# How to Change Server Date?

Tags: linux, bash, date

How do I change a Linux web server's date through SSH?

Answer (score 2):

Use the following syntax to set new data and time:

```
date --set="STRING"
```

Comment: Also here's the formatting of the string inputted: date --set="30 APR 2011 18:46:00"

Answer (score 1):

With the `date` command.  See `man date` for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use the ntpdate command to sync it from a public NTP server, then start up ntpd to keep it in sync.